1.41 GB volume not mounted since oclp/sonoma installation on MBP
I was checking my disks after the successful installation oclp 1.4.3/Sonoma 1.4.1 on a MBP 14,3 2017 with Touch Bar.
Why I have an 1 Not Mounted volume on my main (startup) disk? 
I googled for this situation, I have found the question reported but without answer.

Can Someone explain, please?
Thanks.

Probably the Recovery volume.

I have Ventura on a 2018 Mac mini. I am not using oclp. I have 1.33 GB not mounted. This is slightly larger than the Recovery volume, which is not mounted. The diskutil list command shows the Recovery volume is using 1.1 GB.

Yeah, Thanks. I found it too. It is the recovery volume.

I would suggest you enter the command below.
diskutil mount Recovery

On the Disk Utility, you should see 1 Not Mounted change to Recovery. The size should decrease to what diskutil list shows for the Recovery volume. I suppose the size change can be explained as follows. When mounted, the Disk Utility can examine the Recovery volume and determine space used. When Recovery is unmounted, the Disk Utility computes Not Mounted space by subtracting free space and used space from other volumes in the container from the total space occupied by the container.
Afterwards, you can enter the command below to return Recovery to its original unmounted state.
diskutil unmount Recovery

I tested this on Monterey running as a VMware Fusion Player guest.
Here are some images. Below is before mounting Recovery.

Below is after mounting Recovery.


Yeah, Thanks. That is right. I found that too.
